# How to add Activities section to Case detail page in communities

Tags: community

I want to display Activity timeline in Case detail page of communities.But i am getting an error like Activity timeline is hidden for this object.How can i add NewTask,Log a call,Email actions to the activity tab in communities.All these actions were there in publisher layout too.But not showing up.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of community are you using?

Please go through the below link to know if your template supports such features.

[Template comparision](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_component_reference_table.htm&type=5)